# How to convert .txt files to BDIC format?

Tags: dictionary, text, data-conversion, spell-checking, anki

I was recently looking for a spell checker add-on for [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) and I found this add-on named [(Legacy) Spelling Police™](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1410276506) and here it's [GitHub page](https://github.com/lovac42/SpellingPolice) but the problem is that it needs to feed with user's own dictionaries and that also in [BDIC format](https://www.google.com/search?q=BDIC+format&rlz=1C1RXQR_enIN975IN975&oq=BDIC+format&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i13l4j69i59j0i13l4.1025j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and after looking on the internet for a long time I can only find dictinaries in ***.txt*** format and here is the [link for it](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words.txt).

So, now I need a way to convert this ***.txt*** format to ***.bdic*** format.